# Need help creating a google sheets script or formula

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am in the process of creating a list of parts for our inventory control. I want to automate the system that as inventory is updated on sheet 1, sheet 2 creates a list of items we need to order to keep stock at acceptable levels. So as inventory gets low on sheet1, selected cells from that row are copied over to sheet2 to make a quick order form for my supplier.

I have created a dummy sheet for you to see to make it easier for you to follow. In Column "E" if the number in the cell i.e cell E6 goes higher then 1 cells "A6", "B6", and "E6", get copied over to the second sheet titled "order". That way in the future I can update our current stock levels and instantly have an order ready to place.

Is there any way to do that? or do I just have to keep copy and pasting?

I bumbled around HTML and CSS years ago, but Excel Macros are something I was never able to get my head around. I admit I am out of my depth and any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UXyRWRz--03dmP9qpaSNhVEa17jNxEwNVGmyD5wyC8c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're alright with simply *displaying* a small table with all the items that are under the acceptable threshold, and don't want to edit anything in it, the `QUERY` function might be able to help you. Docs [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).

Clear everything in the order sheet (except for the headers), and then in cell A2 write the following:

```
=QUERY('inventory'!A2:E200,"select A,B,E where D<C")
```

The `QUERY` function kind of works like SQL, so in this case it would return the values from column A, B and E for every entry in the data (*range A2:E200 from the inventory sheet*) where the value from column D (*current stock level*) is lower than the value from column C (*the minimum treshold*).